# Angular2 file input onchange

Tags: file, angular, upload

I have input file (without submit - typicall input file). I'd like to call some function when chose file.

Example:
I click on "Choose file" -> choose file -> now system detects change and call some function which prints all these file information (for example image name).

I can't use ngModel on input file, right? How to do that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the following in your template:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
   <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
   <img id="preview" src="" alt="Preview">
</div>
```

Then your Component `fileChangeEvent()` as

```ts
public fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
      if (fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e : any) {
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);
    }
}
```

All Your File related info will console....

Comment: Thank you, it works. Have you any idea how could I be able to display selected photo? There is no path in fileInput.target.files response.

Comment: And what if i have to submit/upload the same file two times? the change event isn't fired if i choose the same file twice. Is there some sort of submit event i can use?

Comment: Is there a type we can use here instead of "any"? I've got any disabled in my project

Comment: @MartijnvandenBergh see Chris answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my amendments to Double H's answer to not rely on jQuery and stop the webpack erroring out on e.target.result.

```
<img [src]="imageSrc" alt="" />
<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" (change)="displayPhoto($event)">
```

Typescript Code

```
displayPhoto(fileInput) {
  if (fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]) {
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = ((e) => {
    this.imageSrc = e.target['result'];
  });

  reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.target.files[0]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Double H's function didn't work for me till I added onclick="this.value = null" as found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357862/634650