# Input File onchange event not firing

Tags: angular, input

I am trying to fire `onchange` event everytime a file is selected. It does fire if the file I select is different, however, I wanted to fire even if  the same file is selected twice.

**html**

```
  <input name="file" type="file"  (change)="onChange($event)" style="width:80%" />
```

component

```
onChange(event: any) {
   let files = event.srcElement.files;
   this.files = files;
   event= null;
}
```

Comment: You have plenty of other DOM events. If change don't meet your expectation, you can try (input) or (select) or ... see all the DOM events here : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The most reliable way to achieve this cross browser and without having to change much code is to set the value of the input to null on click.

```
onclick="this.value = null"
```

So your input would look like this

```
<input name="file" type="file" onclick="this.value = null" (change)="onChange($event)" style="width:80%"/>
```

Here is an working example: [plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/eEPFXyHvhU8V60q4fCfv/)

Comment: one could as well write `onclick="value = null"` cuz `this` is not required in the template! ´

Comment: i have tried this, but not getting the hit in the change event, it will be really greatfull if you can have look at my sample code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-reader)

Comment: @Webber here you go sir https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-reader-hzcwti

Comment: Why does this work only with `onclick` and not with `(click)`?

Comment: @Gabriel You want to change the value of the input, not the value of an angular variable. The change of the input value will trigger an angular function.

Comment: I was tracking file input changes with a form control `.valueChanges` observable. Odd issue: when I chose a file and cancelled (effective reinitializing the form) and then chose the *same* file again the `valueChanges` never fired the second time. This answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 9):

You need to clear the value of file input. As if you select the file it matches with the value and if value is same then no change event.

You need to use native `onclick` of JS

```
<input name="file" type="file" onclick="value = null" (change)="onChange($event)" style="width:80%"/>
```

if you use Angular's `(click)` then it will set the ts variable `value` which can cause error as it will be not declared in your ts file.

If you want to use angualr's `(click)` event then use template variable like this

```
<input name="file" type="file" (click)="myInputFile.value = null" (change)="onChange($event)" style="width:80%" #myInputFile/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed this problem by setting $event.target.value = '' on click event

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="File" aria-label="File" class="file" (click)= "$event.target.value = ''"
          (change)="uploadData($event)" accept=".csv, .xlsx">
```

This worked for me, you can upload a same file multiple times now.

Comment: Best. It woked for me