# Angular doesn't invoke nativeElement.click() on reload

Tags: angular, typescript

I have kind of a strange behavoir in my angular 4 app.

When I reload the app, nativeElement.click doesnt get invoked. However if I change the route and then go back to the affected route again, it works like a charm.. Any help or hint appreciated!

See code below:

**documents.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DocumentService } from '../shared/services/document.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, RouterState } from '@angular/router';
import { DialogService } from '../shared/services/dialog.service';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'documents',
    templateUrl: 'documents.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['documents.component.css']
})

export class DocumentsComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
    private cols: number;
    @ViewChild('cameraUpload') el:ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('canvas') canvas:ElementRef;

    constructor(private documents: DocumentService,
                private elemRef: ElementRef,
                private dialogService: DialogService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router) {
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.el.nativeElement.click();  // <--- This doesn't always get invoked!
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.cols = Math.ceil(
            this.elemRef.nativeElement.querySelector("div").clientWidth / 220
        );

}
```

Comment: have you put your debugger in ngAfterViewInit and checked the values of this.el?

Comment: I have, it shows just what you would expect _ElementRef_ {nativeElement: input}

Comment: why do you want to invoke click event in component? Also can you create a plunker for the issue?

Comment: in the real project it is not in ngAfterViewInit but in a subscribe function from the dialogService. What I do is ask the user if he wants to upload another file and open the file input dialog programatically after if that is confirmed.. at least thats what i'm trying to accomplish..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355858/input-file-onchange-event-not-firing