# Same image not uploading second time after deletion locally angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to delete the image locally

```
 <input type="file" id="profileUrl" (change)="PicUpload($event)" name="profilePic">


PicUpload(e): void {
    this.imageChangedEvent = e;
    this.image  = e.target.files[0];
  }
```

> For preview:

```
 <img [attr.src]="user.photo" />
```

When i delete this image not from server locally

```
removePic(photo) {
      this.user.photo = '/assets/images/default-profile.png';
      this.fileName = '';
      this.image = '';
      this.imageChangedEvent = '';
      document.getElementById("profileUrl").innerHTML = " ";
    }
```

then when i try to upload the same image again it does not show it in preview i have to upload another one before uploading that image then it shows in preview . Image preview is in base64 format

Any solution Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<input #profileUrl type="file" id="profileUrl" (change)="PicUpload($event)" name="profilePic">
```

In ts file:

```
@ViewChild('profileUrl') profileUrl;

removePic(photo) { 
  ...
  this.profileUrl.nativeElement.value = '';
}
```

Comment: I tried this but second time same image not shown in preview i have to upload another one then the old one then it reflect

Comment: @user3653474 can you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976714/how-to-upload-the-same-file-in-angular4