# Not able to get files data while uploading file in angular2

Tags: angular

i am using angular2 and am trying to get the data of the uploaded file .CSV file but i am not able to get the data of the file. The below is my code

**html**

```
<input type="file" name="File Upload" id="txtFileUpload" 
        (change)="changeListener($event)" 
        accept=".csv"/>
```

**component**

```
 changeListener(fileInput: any): void {
    debugger;
   //want to get the data of the uploaded file
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload a CSV file and read them using angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441962/how-to-upload-a-csv-file-and-read-them-using-angular2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 file input onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38476315/angular2-file-input-onchange)

Comment: that blog has not provided me the answer and i am trying to change the question and ask, the answer which someone has given is not to read the file nut to upload it in a particular location. i dont want to upload the CSV file, i want to read the uploaded .CSV file and get the data

Comment: i dont mind if someone down rate my question for possible duplicate for which i have not received any answer but before down rating please provide me with the answer... thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can get it with this:

```
changeListener(fileInput: any): void {
    var file = event.srcElement.files[0];
}
```

this gives only this details
[image]

Comment: i am not getting the data present in the file, all i can get is the file name and the file type details